# Pybind11 - Function with unknown number of arguments

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I want to get a list of arguments

my current c++ code:

```cpp
m.def("test", [](std::vector<pybind11::object> args){
    return ExecuteFunction("test", args);
});
```

my current python code:

```py
module.test(["-2382.430176", "-610.183594", "12.673874"])
module.test([])
```

I want my python code to look like this:

```py
module.test("-2382.430176", "-610.183594", "12.673874")
module.test()
```

How can I get all arguments passed through Python?

Comment: It's in the doc: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/functions.html#accepting-args-and-kwargs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such generic functions `module.test(*args)` can be created using pybind11:

```
void test(py::args args) {
    // do something with arg
}

// Binding code
m.def("test", &test);
```

Or

```
m.def("test", [](py::args args){
    // do something with arg
});
```

See [Accepting *args and **kwargs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#accepting-args-and-kwargs) and the [example](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/tests/test_kwargs_and_defaults.cpp) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
m.def("test", [](const pybind11::args& args){
    std::vector<pybind11::object> pyArgs;
    for (const auto &arg : args) {
        pyArgs.push_back(arg.cast<pybind11::object>());
    }
    return ExecuteFunction("test", pyArgs);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have to admit I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but here is one idea:

```
def wrapper(args*)
    return module.test(args)
```

There are other ways of making such a wrapper but this should work if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).